# SQL query return column null if not found

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query will return all orgs if it finds a camera of that org, else it wont return a row.

```
SELECT org.id as organization_id, 
 cam.id as device_id,
 org.slug as organization_slug 
 FROM accounts_organization org 
 INNER JOIN devices_camera cam on org.id=cam.owner_id 
 WHERE org.slug IN ('org1','org2') and cam.unique_identifier = '123'
```

How can I change this so it will return all the queried orgs, but if there is no such related camera, then that column field will be null but the row will still be displayed?

Comment: sample data and output helpful

Comment: You should use Left Join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `inner join` to left join and change  `cam.unique_identifier = '123'` to the `on` clause

```
  SELECT org.id as organization_id, 
 cam.id as device_id,
 org.slug as organization_slug 
 FROM accounts_organization org 
 left JOIN devices_camera cam on org.id=cam.owner_id and  cam.unique_identifier = '123'
 WHERE org.slug IN ('org1','org2')
```

Comment: ah perfect!  so simple :-)